# Image in a dialog

Tags: android, imageview, android-dialog

I'm trying to display an ImageView in a dialog, I've followed several examples but none of them seem to work as when I open the dialog the app closes.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:contentDescription="@string/desc1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This is what I have in my MainActivity

```
button1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();

            dialog.setTitle("Title");
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dust);
            dialog.setView(img);

            dialog.show();
            return false;

        }


    });

}
```

Using this new code I have been able to display the dialog with the image inside and I have also been able to rotate the image

```
   button1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);


            RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, 200f, 200f);
            anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
            anim.setDuration(10000);

            dialog.setTitle("You have found the easter egg!");
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, null);
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            view.startAnimation(anim);

            dialog.show();
            return false;

        }


    });

}
```

Comment: check out how to make custom dialog http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog

Comment: What is the xml layout file name where ImageView is available???

Comment: The xml layout file is Activity_Main

Comment: The New code is same as my answer. Isn't it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
when I open the dialog the app closes.
```

Because your dialog `ImageView img` is **null**

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image); // <--- img is not visible through dialog..
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dust); // <--- this line throw exception
```

Just Change your code like this,

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("Title");
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<xml_image>, null); // xml Layout file for imageView
ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dust);
dialog.setView(view);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: Well if our image resource is an animation-list how can animate image

Answer (score 3):

You should not use AlertDialog for your custom dialog. 
Use regular Dialog class and it's setContentView() method. Or you can use DialogFragment.

UPD: I have been told that AlertDialog has setView() method. You can try it.

Comment: Sorry for -1.. Its me.. You can use setView() in AlertDailog.

Comment: What is not working? Exception? Or image doesn't appear? Update the post please with new code.